# Google Assistant test app unavailable in my country

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I've been following [this](https://blog.prototypr.io/using-voice-to-control-a-website-with-google-home-part-1-3-d2355327f250) tutorial on using Dialogflow and Firebase so I can control a simple website, but when trying to `Talk to <app name>` I receive the response

> <app name> isn't available on devices set up for your language or
>   country. Sorry about that.

I am located in New Zealand, but I did go into the settings for my google assistant and change the search language to English (US) and my search region to United States, although I get the same results, is there any way I can fix this or is there any way around it? Thanks

Comment: Did you select the list of countries in the action console?

Comment: What language/locale are you using in your phone's settings?

Comment: @SergeHendrickx Yeah I had added English (US) and English (Australia) added just in case, and after reading Nick Felker's reply I changed my default from English (New Zealand) to English (US) and now I can test my app via my phone, thanks for the help fellas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following Nick Felker's comment, changing my phone's locale to English (US) enabled me to test the app. Thanks Nick!

Comment: Can you please give a more detailed answer?